# Resultset metadata as header for CSV file in Spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am writing a code to generate CSV file from result set of a SQL stored procedure. I made almost everything generic by using Spring Batch framework itself but except header.I want resultset's metadata as the header. I don't want to extend `StoredProcedureItemReader` and do it. Is there any class/item in Spring Batch framework to write a header like I asked above or is there any property in `StoredProcedureItemReader` or in `FlatFileItemWriter` to do this one. I want it generic because I want to use the same code for multiple Stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

spring Batch provides `FlatFileHeaderCallback` for creating file header. 
You need to implement the `writeHeader(Writer writer)` method.

In WriteHeader method you need to write Something like this.

1 Inject `JdbcTemplate` in that class

then

```
List<ColumList> list = jdbcTemplate.query("Select * From table where 1=2",new YourMapper())
```

In Mapper- from `ResultSet` Object you can get `ResultSetMetaData`*.
Now using `ResultSetMetaData` you can get list of all **ColumnNames**. 
then return this list from mapper

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  Can I get something without using jdbcTemplate because database reader already executed the query and returned the resultset. Can't I get the resultset from reader itself.

Comment: You would need to create a custom `ItemReader` that extracts the metadata into the `ExecutionContext` so that it's available across the components.

Comment: Vishal if you don't want to run the query again then you need to custom ItemReader and add metadata to ExecutionContext what Michael has mentioned.
Use this ExecutionContext in writeHeader method.

If answer help you please accept it so that's others can also use the same.

Comment: Actually I tried to get metadata in rowmapper once. But this is called only after header is written down. Can you post me some example on this.

Comment: Added some sample code , Please check in separate answer

Comment: Added my code as a separate answer. Please check it and give a solution

Answer (score 0):

implement `FlatFileHeaderCallback` like this

```
public class TestClass implements FlatFileHeaderCallback  {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; //IF you have jdbcTemplate bean or use data source run the SQL


    @Override
    public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {


        List<String> list = jdbcTemplate.query("Select * From table where 1=2",new YourMapper()) ;
        list.toString();
        writer.write(list.toString());      
    }

}
```

Mapper will be something like this

```
public class YourDBMapper implements ResultSetExtractor<List<String>> {

    List<String> list = new List<>();
    @Override
    public List<String> extractData(ResultSet rs){      

        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();    

        for (int i = 1; i <=  meta.getColumnCount(); i++) 
            list.add(meta.getColumnName(i));        

        return list;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had something like below in my code to get metadata

```
    @Scope("step")
    public class CustomColumnMapRowMapper extends ColumnMapRowMapper{
    private static boolean isMetadataSet = false;
    @Autowired
    private StepExecution stepExecution;
    @Autowired
    private String delimiter;

    private String metadata="";
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Inside custom row mapper "+this.getClass().getName());
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        Map<String, Object> mapOfColValues = createColumnMap(columnCount);
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            String key = getColumnKey(JdbcUtils.lookupColumnName(rsmd, i));
            if(!this.isMetadataSet){
                if(i==columnCount){
                    metadata=metadata.concat(key);
                    break;
                }
                metadata=metadata.concat(key).concat(delimiter);
            }
            Object obj = getColumnValue(rs, i);
            mapOfColValues.put(key, obj);
        }
        if(!this.isMetadataSet){
            this.stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("metadata", this.metadata);
            this.isMetadataSet = true;
            System.out.println("Metadata retrieved is "+this.stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get("metadata"));
        }

        //System.out.println("Metadata is "+this.metadata);
        return mapOfColValues;
    }
```

It is working but the problem here is header is called before the above rowmapper. Please see below for the CustomFlatFileHeader

```
public class CustomFlatFileHeader implements FlatFileHeaderCallback{

    @Autowired
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Metdata in col header");
        writer.write(this.stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get("metadata").toString());
    }

    public StepExecution getStepExecution() {
        return stepExecution;
    }

    public void setStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        System.out.println("Inside step exec setting ");
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }
}
```

Please see to my job configuration

```
<batch:job id="ReportJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="databaseItemReader" writer="flatFileItemWriter"
                processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="100" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jobListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```